# how to get the resulting HTML from a MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get the resulting HTML that is outputting from an action via code?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MvcIntegrationTestFramework](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/)

Answer (score 0):

To be specific on why you would look at [MvcIntegrationTestFramework](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/).

It makes saves you writing your own helpers to stream result and is proven to work well enough.  I'd assume this would be in a test project and as a bonus you would have the other testing capabilities once you've got this setup.  Main bother would probably be sorting out the dependency chain.

```
 private static readonly string mvcAppPath = 
     Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 
     + "\\..\\..\\..\\MyMvcApplication");
        private readonly AppHost appHost = new AppHost(mvcAppPath);

    [Test]
    public void Root_Url_Renders_Index_View()
    {
        appHost.SimulateBrowsingSession(browsingSession => {
            RequestResult result = browsingSession.ProcessRequest("");
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ResponseText.Contains("<!DOCTYPE html"));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I have done it in Razor syntax.  I needed to get the html from one action as a string in another action (to the render as a pdf)

```
 ViewResult viewResult = ActionYouWhatHtmlFrom(id);

       using (var writer = new StringWriter())
       {
           ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines
                     .Engines
                     .FindView(ControllerContext,
                               viewResult.ViewName, "_YourLayout");


           var viewPath = ((RazorView)result.View).ViewPath;
           var layoutPath = ((RazorView) result.View).LayoutPath;

           var view = new RazorView(ControllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, true, null);
           var viewCxt = new ViewContext(
                               ControllerContext,
                               view,
                               viewResult.ViewData,
                               viewResult.TempData, writer);
           viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
```